# Retrieve all related activites of an account - Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-365

I would like to get rid of the Social Pane on Dynamics 365, by replacing it with a Subgrid on the account form which would list the activities of the account and the activities of the account's contacts. We are currently using the "parentcustomerid" lookup to associate a contact to an account which is not hierarchical. I cannot find a solution with FetchXML to get what I want. The following FetchXML would work if there was a hierarchical relation:

```
<fetch>
<entity name="activitypointer" >
<attribute name="activityid" />
<attribute name="regardingobjectid" />
<attribute name="subject" />
<attribute name="regardingobjecttypecode" />
<filter type="and" >
  <condition attribute="isregularactivity" operator="eq" value="1" />
  <filter type="or" >
    <condition entityname="accountparty" attribute="accountid" operator="eq-or-under" value="5D8E9289-7F86-E811-910D-0050568B95ED" />
    <condition entityname="contactparty" attribute="contactid" operator="eq-or-under" value="5D8E9289-7F86-E811-910D-0050568B95ED" />
  </filter>
</filter>
<link-entity name="activityparty" from="activityid" to="activityid" link-type="outer" alias="activityparty" >
  <link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="partyid" link-type="outer" alias="accountparty" />
  <link-entity name="contact" from="contactid" to="partyid" link-type="outer" alias="contactparty" >
    <link-entity name="account" from="accountid" to="parentcustomerid" link-type="outer" alias="contactaccount" />
  </link-entity>
</link-entity>
```

The goal is to have a plugin that catches the query in pre-operation in order to add the conditions and filters needed.

Comment: This was not allowed as an answer, so I just write it as a comment: This is a solution to your problem https://jonasrapp.net/2016/05/hierarchy-activities/

Comment: @JonasRapp I've found this link before and it helped me understand but the relation between contacts and account is made through "parentcustomerid" which is not a hierarchical relationship so it cannot work unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this by linking the activities related to contacts directly to their parent `account`, with a custom lookup in the activity entity and probably a `Retrieve/RetrieveMultiple` plugin to automagically fill it based on if the `regardingobjectid` is a `contact`.

Done that, you only need to refer to that field in the grid.

We used a similar approach to make a "rollup of rollups" spanning more than 1 relationship.

Comment: I can't recall the specifics at the moment, but maybe a plugin is not even needed and the parent account can be filled with a BR or a realtime workflow

Comment: Yep, might be an idea

Answer (score 1):

This kind of rollup is easy to achieve with custom HTML webresource with bootstrap & our own js libraries to handle web api calls/fetchxml queries. We are doing this today.

As we cannot do `UNION` in fetchxml, we may have to merge couple of resultsets, so we can use jQuery datatables to merge/visualize the results.

Also this approach is easy to amend, debug rather intercepting server calls for custom fetchxml queries.

Answer (score 0):

As you are have concluded already, the core to solve this is to use the `UnderOrEqual` condition with the query.

This feature may be difficult (afaik it is impossible) to implement in the way you want to by using the View Designer. So you need to add some code to make this happen.

While the approach to create custom webresources and use a custom grid might be easier to debug, it will require quite a lot of custom code and controls.

Another approach would be to add a standard subgrid with an "Associated View" for activities related to the parent account to the form, then add a pre `RetrieveMultiple` plugin that identifies the query and then tweaks the query to work for your needs.

You are then using standard controls and features, that will be upgradeable and still follow possible design changes from Microsoft etc.

To see a fully working ready to use solution, the following article describes this pattern in detail:
https://jonasrapp.net/2016/05/hierarchy-activities/

Comment: As I said as an answer to your comment, I have to use the native "parentcustomerid" reference on the contact form that links a contact to an account (1:n relation) and it's not hierarchical. Otherwise this solution would be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @HubertSolecki Okay, got it... But still... hm.... I think it should be possible, adding some link-entity and then the hierarchical relationship under that... But it's been some time since I tried last.